# Azure Active Directory B2C Identity: identity verification and proofing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, verification

I would like to use the Azure B2C Identity Service for customer self registration, but I would like to add a manual verification. The user shall upload a scan of his ID card / passport. And shall not be granted (full) access before the manual verification by our back office.

Is such process possible out of the box, as I could only find a slide, but no more details or documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview#third-party-identity-verification-and-proofing

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [customised user journey](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/putting-together-a-user-journey-in-azure-ad-b2c-34c78d2c4a86).

Each step would call [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw) to do verfification etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution.

You need to customize the user journey by referring to the custom policy.

Please refer to: [Custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).